# 3D Plotting in R - Using a 4th dimension of color

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I am using the plot3d function to make a 3d plot in my R script. I'd like to add a 4th dimension, which will be color. How can I do this?

Specifically, assume I have the following code:

```
plot3d(x, y, z, col=cols, size=2, type='s')
```

how would I populate `cols` based on a vector of values acting as my 4th dimension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just make a colormap, and then index into it with a cut version of your c variable:

```
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
z = rnorm(100)

c = z
c = cut(c, breaks=64)
cols = rainbow(64)[as.numeric(c)]

plot3d(x,y,z,col=cols)
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of `rainbow`.  Very nice!

Comment: but how could I add a scale on the side showing my range of colors...like a legend for the colors

Comment: Yea it is very flexible and lets you set the start/end hues, etc.. Under the rainbow help there are also a few other built-in color maps too. Good luck!

Comment: and how did you choose 64? is this an arbitrary number? can you explain what this does?

Comment: @CodeGuy I believe rgl still doesn't have any legend/HUD ability. I've always just added the legend into the figure after the fact. I use a little convenience function I made (http://www.colbyimaging.com/wiki/statistics/color-bars), which of course you're welcome to have.

Comment: 64 is arbitrary...it's just how "smooth" do you want the color transitions. Sometimes smoother is more useful; sometimes not.

Comment: can you show me how I could use your function to add a color bar?

Comment: so to make it very smooth, I could make it a really large number? thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `color.bar(rainbow(64), min(c), max(c), title='C', ticks=round(seq(min(c), max(c), len=11), 2))` would be one way to do it. http://i.imgur.com/CGBrQ.png

Comment: Correct...a big number will mean very smooth.

Comment: when I include the color.bar line you posted, i get the following error:Error in Summary.factor(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,  : 
  max not meaningful for factors

Comment: Make the color bar before you turn c into a factor. Or keep the original version around instead of overwriting it.

Comment: You know-- in this answer, color is not a "4th dimension".  It's simply highlighting z-values, aka the third dimension. You can do this stuff with the "drape" tool in wireframe(), for example.  A true 4th dimension color would assign colors to some other data attribute. E.g., `mydata<-data.frame(x,y,z,t)` , and use `colors=rainbow(42)[cut(t,42)]` -- sort of thing.  (And always use 42, since that's the answer to the ultimate question...)

Comment: Right. I only chose to reuse z here so that it was clear it was working.

Comment: yeah, instead of cut(z...) i plug in my 4th dimension. is this wrong?

Comment: Typo...should be `c = cut(c, ...)`, whatever you choose for your `c`.